# How can I simplify this code

Tags: python

I'm a beginner, and I wanted to know if there was a simpler way of write this out in Python.  I'm assuming some type of dictionary, but I do not understand how to write it out.
I was on a cruise a couple of days ago, and I play craps.  I wanted to know if the odds are somewhat correct.  So, I wrote this, but I know there is a simpler way.

```
import random

dice2 = 0
dice3 = 0
dice4 = 0
dice5 = 0
dice6 = 0
dice7 = 0
dice8 = 0
dice9 = 0
dice10 = 0
dice11 = 0
dice12 = 0

for i in range(100000):
            dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
            dice2 = random.randint(1,6)
            number = dice1 + dice2
            #print(dice1)
            if number == 2:
                        dice2 +=1
            elif number == 3:
                        dice3 += 1
            elif number == 4:
                        dice4 += 1
            elif number == 5:
                        dice5 += 1
            elif number == 6:
                        dice6 += 1
            elif number == 7:
                        dice7 += 1
            elif number == 8:
                        dice8 += 1
            elif number == 9:
                        dice9 += 1
            elif number == 10:
                        dice10 += 1
            elif number == 11:
                        dice11 += 1
            elif number == 12:
                        dice12 += 1

total = dice2+dice3+dice4+dice5+dice6+dice7+dice8+dice9+dice10+dice11+dice12
```

At the end of this, it just prints out the percentage of hits on numbers from 2-12.

Comment: Learn to use containing data-structures... You can simplify this using a list, tuple, or dictionary.

Comment: The singular of "dice" is "die", by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from random import randint

dice = [0]*11
for i in range(100000):
    dice[randint(1,6)+randint(1,6)-2] += 1

total = sum(dice) #it is 100000, of course
for i, v in enumerate(dice, 2):
    print('{0}: {1}%'.format(i, v*100.0/total))
```

Comment: I chose this as the correct one, but all of the other answers work as well, but I understand this code the most at my basic understanding at the moment.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), as that's what it was made for:

```
from random import randint
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6) for i in range(100000))
total = sum(counts.values())
number_of_tens = counts[10]
```

Comment: Personally, it's a little harder for me to see what you did there.

Comment: @Elazar I was just commenting for the sake of having a link to the python docs right there. Instead, I've added it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
import random

def roll(n=6):
    return random.randint(1, n)

dice = dict.fromkeys(range(2, 13), 0)

for i in range(100000):
    number = roll() + roll()
    dice[number] += 1

total = float(sum(dice.values()))
for k,v in dice.items():
    print "{}, {:.2%}".format(k, v/total)
```

Comment: Or instead of `.fromkeys` you could use `collections.defaultdict(int)`

Comment: @AlexL, but that doesn't guarantee that all the keys will get in there

Comment: This would be my 2nd choice, from my current understanding.  Thank you.

Comment: @nrvswreck, you should learn from this code to seperate your tasks to little easy bits. It's very important.

Comment: @gnibbler Good point, although statistically speaking I think it's pretty likely